# python StringIO with urlli2.urlopen mocked with unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have an interesting problem.  I am mocking urllib2.urlopen with the python  mock library as follows:

```
def mock_url_open_conn_for_json_feed():
    json_str = """
        {"actions":[{"causes":[{"shortDescription":"Started by user anonymous","userId":null,"userName":"anonymous"}]}],"artifacts":[],"building":false,"description":null,"duration":54,"estimatedDuration":54,
        "fullDisplayName":"test3#1",
        "id":"2012-08-24_14-10-34","keepLog":false,"number":1,"result":"SUCCESS","timestamp":1345842634000,
        "url":"http://localhost:8080/job/test3/1/","builtOn":"","changeSet":{"items":[],"kind":null},"culprits":[]}
        """
    return StringIO(json_str)

def test_case_foo(self):
    io = mock_url_open_conn_for_json_feed()
    io.seek(0)
    mylib.urllib2.urlopen = Mock(return_value=io)
    test_obj.do_your_thing()

def test_case_foo_bar(self)
    io = mock_url_open_conn_for_json_feed()
    io.seek(0)
    mylib.urllib2.urlopen = Mock(return_value=io)
    test_obj.param = xyz
    test_obj.do_your_thing()

class ObjUnderTest():
    def do_your_thing(self):
        conn = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        simplejson.load(conn)
```

the first unit test "test_case_foo" runs without a problem.  But simplejson.load closes the StringIO, so "test_case_foo_bar" calls on do_your_thing() and it tries to simplejson.load the same StringIO object (even though I return the *constructor* of StringIO), and it's already been closed.  I get the following error:

```
json = simplejson.load(conn)
 File "/Users/sam/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 391, in load
return loads(fp.read(),
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/StringIO.py", line 127, in read
_complain_ifclosed(self.closed)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/StringIO.py", line 40, in _complain_ifclosed
raise ValueError, "I/O operation on closed file"
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

I have two questions:

1) Why is the StringIO constructor not returning a new object?

2) Is there a work around for this? Or a better way to achieve what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: Something is fishy ...
If I do :
    >>> from StringIO import StringIO
    >>> s = "gaga"
    >>> s1 = StringIO(s)
    >>> s2 = StringIO(s)
    >>> s1
    <StringIO.StringIO instance at 0x24bc830>
    >>> s2
    <StringIO.StringIO instance at 0x24bc680>
    >>> s1.read()
    'gaga'
    >>> s2.read()
    'gaga'
    >>> 
No problem at all...

Comment: I could bet there is a bug somewhere in Mock or the way you handle "url" in the ObjUnderTest because as it is presented it should work cf my serie of commands on my precedent comment

Comment: Interesting.  I just do a straight up read with urllib2.urlopen('http://localhost:8080/jenkines/view')

Comment: i confirmed that they are in fact two different instances.  so i have to check what's happening in simplejosn.load or in my ObjectUnderTest

Comment: Why not "io = StringIO(mock_url_open_conn_for_json_feed())" ?